# Chrome Open in New Tab/Window Menu Items

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs, context-menu, user-interface

Firefox and Internet Explorer both have "Open in New Tab" as the second option, whereas Chrome has it as the first option.

[image]

This has become muscle memory for me by now, to the point that I don't use as often as I want to, solely because I can't open a page in a new tab without thinking about it.

Is there a way to switch the position of "Open Link in new tab" and "Open link in new window", so that I can resume browsing as normal, or am I cursed by this user interface design nightmare by Google?

Comment: I think you're stuck with the context menu as is, but +1 for an thought provoking question.

Comment: If you want new tab, just shift+click on the link ;-) Problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that a simple resource editor could reposition the menu items in the .exe too without recompiling.  Try that out.

You could always work around the issue too.  In almost every browser, Middle-Mouse-Click'ing a link will open in a new tab.  This is true in Opera, Safari, Chrome, I.E., and FireFox at least.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using Middle Mouse Click! That is quicker and works on all, so I can get used to it at least.

Answer (score 1):

Others have had [**the same question**](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6fa4cc96a9e6cd7b&hl=en), and the answer seems to currently be **no** (from the UI at least). Although you may be interested in [**Chromium**](http://code.google.com/chromium/) seeing as you have programming experience, judging by your profile. This way you can modify the order in the source code and recompile it for yourself! :)

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction:

- new tab opens with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click on the link;
- new window opens with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on the link;